# Edit dataframe by slice

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill in the columns of a dataframe in "chunks", because I am getting the data from an instrument in said chunks.

I get waveform data from an oscilloscope in lengths of `250e3`. There is potentially `24e6` data points. I need to get this into a dataframe, and update the dataframe as the data becomes available.

```py
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((10, 3)), columns=['a','b','c'])
for i in range(5):
    ser = pd.Series(data=[i+1,i+1])
    ser[0:2]
    df4['a'].iloc[i*2:(i+1)*2] = ser[0:2]
    df4
```

I'd like the values in the series to show up in the dataframe column. It works for the first pass through the loop, but then `NaN` shows up. How come? 
Also, I'm open to other ideas if they execute faster.

Comment: Create df and then show us sample what you want to receive;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((10, 3)), columns=['a','b','c'])
for i in range(5):
    ser = pd.Series(data=[i+1,i+1])
    print(ser[0:2])
    df4.loc[[i*2], 'a'] = ser[0]
    df4.loc[[(i+1)*2-1], 'a'] = ser[1]
    print(df4)
```

Alternatively, there is a much better way to achieve this using below code:

```
df4.loc[i*2:(i+1)*2-1, 'a'] = ser[0],ser[1]
```